# Close previous drawer before opening next - Twitter bootstrap 3

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

With Bootstrap 3 I will use `collapse` to have multiple columns, each with one collapsible drawer. When clicking one drawer, the reviously opened drawer should close (using the collapse animation) before opening the next one. The drawers have to be next to each other, and can not be below/ontop each other, therfore the bootstraps `accordion` is out of the question.

How can I achieve this?

Look here: [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/j9JCr/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/M57Ra/) of how this could work. The main point to take away is that the accordian-style automatic closing of open drawers only works if there is a parent container and that parent container is referenced using `<... data-parent="#parent" ...>` when creating the links/buttons.

Comment: Thank you Adam, this is just what i was looking for. I'm sure this answer will help many frontenders!!